# When i use CloseHandle(); why is Event still visible/running

Tags: c++, winapi

I believe that calling `CloseHandle()` only closes the reference made to the handle? But the Event is still visible in Process Explorer, and the desired functionality isn't met.

```cpp
HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
{
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "program.exe") == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
            HANDLE hEvent = OpenEventA(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,"openEvent");
            // Do stuff..

            int sucess = CloseHandle(hEvent);
        }
    }
    count = 0;
}
CloseHandle(snapshot);
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Why would the Event still be visible in Process Explorer?

Comment: I would assume because CloseHandle does not terminate the process, it just closes the handle.

Comment: Since you're able to open the event, it must already exist - that increments the use count, `CloseHandle` decrements it again, but it does not reach zero, so the event remains.

Comment: Only way to get rid of it, if that's your goal, is to close all outstanding handles on it.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel objects are reference counted. Calling `CloseHandle` decrements the reference count, but the referenced object doesn't get removed, until the final handle to it gets closed.

In the code for `OpenEventA` to return a non-NULL value, the event referenced by name must already exist (i.e. its reference count must be at least 1). `OpenEventA` increments the reference count, and `CloseHandle` decrements it, but it's still at least 1 (unless the other handles to that event object have been closed).

Consequently the event object doesn't get closed, and Process Explorer rightfully reports that the event object still exists.